# Failover pacemaker cluster with two network interfaces?

Tags: cluster, failover, pacemaker, corosync

So, i have two test servers in one vlan.

```
srv1
  eth1 10.10.10.11
  eth2 10.20.10.11

srv2
  eth1 10.10.10.12
  eth2 10.20.10.12

Cluster VIP - 10.10.10.100
```

Corosync config with two interfaces:

```
  rrp_mode: passive

  interface {
    ringnumber: 0
    bindnetaddr: 10.10.10.0
    mcastaddr: 226.94.1.1
    mcastport: 5405
  }

  interface {
    ringnumber: 1
    bindnetaddr: 10.20.10.0
    mcastaddr: 226.94.1.1
    mcastport: 5407
  }
```

Pacemaker config:

```
# crm configure show
node srv1
node srv2
primitive cluster-ip ocf:heartbeat:IPaddr2 \
    params ip="10.10.10.100" cidr_netmask="24" \
    op monitor interval="5s"
primitive ha-nginx lsb:nginx \
    op monitor interval="5s"
location prefer-srv-2 ha-nginx 50: srv2
colocation nginx-and-cluster-ip +inf: ha-nginx cluster-ip
property $id="cib-bootstrap-options" \
    dc-version="1.1.6-9971ebba4494012a93c03b40a2c58ec0eb60f50c" \
    cluster-infrastructure="openais" \
    expected-quorum-votes="2" \
    no-quorum-policy="ignore" \
    stonith-enabled="false"
```

Status:

```
# crm status
============
Last updated: Thu Jan 29 13:40:16 2015
Last change: Thu Jan 29 12:47:25 2015 via crmd on srv1
Stack: openais
Current DC: srv2 - partition with quorum
Version: 1.1.6-9971ebba4494012a93c03b40a2c58ec0eb60f50c
2 Nodes configured, 2 expected votes
2 Resources configured.
============

Online: [ srv1 srv2 ]

 cluster-ip (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2):   Started srv2
 ha-nginx   (lsb:nginx):    Started srv2
```

Rings:

```
# corosync-cfgtool -s
Printing ring status.
Local node ID 185207306
RING ID 0
    id  = 10.10.10.11
    status  = ring 0 active with no faults
RING ID 1
    id  = 10.20.10.11
    status  = ring 1 active with no faults
```

And, if i do `srv2# ifconfig eth1 down`, pacemaker still works over eth2, and that's ok.
*But* nginx not available on 10.10.10.100 (becouse eth1 down, ya), *and* pacemeker says, that everything ok.

But, I want the nginx moves to srv1 after eth1 dies on srv2.

So, what can i do for that?

Comment: your colocation "colocation nginx-and-cluster-ip +inf: ha-nginx cluster-ip" is strange, positive score need to be inf: without a plush in front

Comment: @c4f4t0r, it's ok, i tested it event without a plus, and it works the same: na-nginx and cluster-ip on one node.

Comment: others importan thing, if your cluster doesn't needs to be grow in number of nodes, you can switch to unicast, because multicast is for large cluster and your need to do more overhead in your switch.

Comment: @c4f4t0r It will be 2 or 3 nodes, so thanks for advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I resolve my issue with ocf:pacemaker:ping, thanks to @Dok.

```
# crm configure show
node srv1
node srv2
primitive P_INTRANET ocf:pacemaker:ping \
  params host_list="10.10.10.11 10.10.10.12" multiplier="100" name="ping_intranet" \
  op monitor interval="5s" timeout="5s"
primitive cluster-ip ocf:heartbeat:IPaddr2 \
  params ip="10.10.10.100" cidr_netmask="24" \
  op monitor interval="5s"
primitive ha-nginx lsb:nginx \
  op monitor interval="5s"
clone CL_INTRANET P_INTRANET \
  meta globally-unique="false"
location L_CLUSTER_IP_PING_INTRANET cluster-ip \
  rule $id="L_CLUSTER_IP_PING_INTRANET-rule" ping_intranet: defined ping_intranet
location L_HA_NGINX_PING_INTRANET ha-nginx \
  rule $id="L_HA_NGINX_PING_INTRANET-rule" ping_intranet: defined ping_intranet
location L_INTRANET_01 CL_INTRANET 100: srv1
location L_INTRANET_02 CL_INTRANET 100: srv2
colocation nginx-and-cluster-ip 1000: ha-nginx cluster-ip
property $id="cib-bootstrap-options" \
  dc-version="1.1.6-9971ebba4494012a93c03b40a2c58ec0eb60f50c" \
  cluster-infrastructure="openais" \
  expected-quorum-votes="2" \
  no-quorum-policy="ignore" \
  stonith-enabled="false"
```

Answer (score 1):

The ocf:pacemaker:pingd resource was designed precisely to failover a node over upon loss of connectivity. You may find a very brief example of this on the cluster labs wiki here:
http://clusterlabs.org/wiki/Example_configurations#Set_up_pingd

Somewhat unrelated, but I have seen issues in the past with using `ifconfig down` to test loss of connectivity. I would strongly encourage that you instead use iptables to drop traffic to test loss of connectivity.

Comment: I tried it, and it works good, but only if it a 100% connectivity loss. But when i only ~50% packet loss - it works awful - pacemaker change active node about 5 times a minute. How can i fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The ping monitor is not sufficient for this scenario for multiple reasons.  what do you ping?  In linux, the local ip still pings when the interface is down (which is BAD, it should not), but what if you ping the default gateway?  There are a bunch of things outside of the cluster that can cause default gateway ping loss, almost *all* of which have nothing to do with health of the cluster's local network connection.

Pacemaker needs to have a method to monitor the network interface UP/DOWN status.  That is the best indication of local network problems.  I haven't found any way to do this yet, and it's a horrible flaw in pacemaker clusters as far as i can tell.

Comment: ah HA!  I found the 'ocf:heartbeat:ethmonitor' resource in CentOS 8 pacemaker.  THIS looks promising.  I will test...