# Failover pacemaker cluster, packet loss monitor

Tags: high-availability, pacemaker, packetloss

It's issue is continued from [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/663394/failover-pacemaker-cluster-with-two-network-interfaces/664281#664281).

So, i have two test servers in one vlan.

```
srv1
  eth1 10.10.10.11
  eth2 10.20.10.11

srv2
  eth1 10.10.10.12
  eth2 10.20.10.12

Cluster VIP - 10.10.10.100
```

Corosync config with two interfaces:

```
  rrp_mode: passive

  interface {
    ringnumber: 0
    bindnetaddr: 10.10.10.0
    mcastaddr: 226.94.1.1
    mcastport: 5405
  }

  interface {
    ringnumber: 1
    bindnetaddr: 10.20.10.0
    mcastaddr: 226.94.1.1
    mcastport: 5407
  }
```

Pacemaker config:

```
# crm configure show
node srv1
node srv2
primitive P_INTRANET ocf:pacemaker:ping \
  params host_list="10.10.10.11 10.10.10.12" multiplier="100" name="ping_intranet" \
  op monitor interval="5s" timeout="5s"
primitive cluster-ip ocf:heartbeat:IPaddr2 \
  params ip="10.10.10.100" cidr_netmask="24" \
  op monitor interval="5s"
primitive ha-nginx lsb:nginx \
  op monitor interval="5s"
clone CL_INTRANET P_INTRANET \
  meta globally-unique="false"
location L_CLUSTER_IP_PING_INTRANET cluster-ip \
  rule $id="L_CLUSTER_IP_PING_INTRANET-rule" ping_intranet: defined ping_intranet
location L_HA_NGINX_PING_INTRANET ha-nginx \
  rule $id="L_HA_NGINX_PING_INTRANET-rule" ping_intranet: defined ping_intranet
location L_INTRANET_01 CL_INTRANET 100: srv1
location L_INTRANET_02 CL_INTRANET 100: srv2
colocation nginx-and-cluster-ip 1000: ha-nginx cluster-ip
property $id="cib-bootstrap-options" \
  dc-version="1.1.6-9971ebba4494012a93c03b40a2c58ec0eb60f50c" \
  cluster-infrastructure="openais" \
  expected-quorum-votes="2" \
  no-quorum-policy="ignore" \
  stonith-enabled="false"
```

And now, i simulate packet loss on eth1:

```
# tc qdisc add dev eth1 root netem delay 200ms 500ms 75% loss 42% 75% duplicate 1% corrupt 0.1% reorder 25% 50%
```

After it, pacemaker changes active node few times per minute, and nothing works correctly.

How can i monitor packet loss and switch node when it's about 15%?

Is there a solution for this? Or i need to write new resource-agent to monitor it by myself?